# Delete custom post type in front end and redirect to specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, frontend

I made it possible to delete the post from the front end with this code (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/132196/get-delete-post-link-redirect):

`<a class="button-iv" onclick="return confirm('are you sure...?');" href="<?php echo  get_delete_post_link( $post->ID ); ?>" title="delete doc">Delete doc</a>`

In functions.php i have this code for redirect after deleting the post:

```
function wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get() {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'trashed', $_GET ) && $_GET['trashed'] == '1' ) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
       wp_redirect( home_url('/doc-area/doc') );
       exit;
    }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get' );
```

This works fine. But now I would like to create a different redirect for each custom post type.
So I add this control

```
if ( 'extra' == get_post_type() )
```

And the function become:

```
function wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get() {
if ('extra' == get_post_type()) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'trashed', $_GET ) && $_GET['trashed'] == '1' ) {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/doc-area/doc') );
        exit;
       }
      }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get' );
```

But now the redirect doesn't work.
How can I get a redirect for each specific post type?

Comment: probably get_post_type != 'extra'

Comment: ...Why a  denial?

Comment: your redirect works just if get_post_type() is equal to 'extra'. If it does not work, probably get_post_type() is not equal to 'extra'

Comment: I am deleting the right custom post type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my modest solution. Thanks to Bhautik.

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get' );
function wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get( $query ) {
if ( array_key_exists( 'trashed', $_GET ) && $_GET['trashed'] == '1' ) {
if (!is_admin() && 'extra' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url('/doc-area/doc') );
        exit;
       }
      }
if ( array_key_exists( 'trashed', $_GET ) && $_GET['trashed'] == '1' ) {
if (!is_admin() && 'lesson' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/lessons-area/lessons') );
        exit;
       }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the parameter in the `parse_request` action hook to check what post type is. check the below code.

```
function wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get( $extra_query_vars ) {
    if ( $extra_query_vars['query_vars']['post_type'] ==  'extra' ) { // $extra_query_vars['extra_query_vars']['post_type']
        if ( array_key_exists( 'trashed', $_GET ) && $_GET['trashed'] == '1' ) {
            if (!is_admin()) {
                wp_redirect( home_url('/doc-area/doc') );
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get' );
```